# Why incrementing int primitive in while loop does not loop forever

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

I have a following code sample

```
int i = 1;  

while(i != 0) {  
    i++;  
}
```

I was expecting this to run in an infinite loop but it didn't. Then when I printed the value after while loop I got:

```
i value is 0.
```

Can any one let me know what exactly is happening?

Comment: More importantly, why do you think that it *should* lead to memory problems? Where is memory being used up here?

Comment: `Can any one let me know what exactly is happening?` -- Integer overflow.

Comment: "I was expecting this to run in an infinite loop but it didn't." If you want an infinite loop, you can do "while (true) {}"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I was expecting this to run in an infinite loop but it didn't.

No, it wouldn't. *Eventually* the value will become 0 again.

In particular, it will logically execute like this:

```
1
2
3
...
2,147,483,646
2,147,483,647  
-2,147,483,648  // Integer overflow => wrapping
-2,147,483,647
...
-3
-2
-1
0
```

... then the loop will end

From [section 15.18.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

There are no *memory* issues with this code because it doesn't perform any allocations - it just increments a local variable, entirely on the stack.

Now whether or not it *actually* does that is a different matter - if the JIT is able to work out what the behaviour will be without executing every iteration, it can optimize it away - but that's an implementation detail. The important part is understanding the logic behind the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah It was so silly that I was expecting heap memory exception instead of stack over flow error. But now I came to know why it was not running in an infinite loop and why there are no errors.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji: Why would you even expect a stack overflow? No more stack memory is being allocated within the loop either - it's just replacing one value with another.

Answer (score 4):

An `int` is an `int`: For each `i`, if `i` is an `int` so is `i+1`. An `int` is always 32-bits, it never requires a larger container.

Last, your loop is not infinite.